# how we can use undefined property in ng model in angular

Tags: angularjs

just got a code and see the code is working but in `ng-model` author use user.name or user.email etc but those property never has been declared in controller.........then how it is working?

how we can pass user info to controller function this way `ng-click="update(user)"` ?

### code

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br />
    Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />
    <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save" />
  </form>
  <pre>user = {{user | json}}</pre>
  <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.master = {};

      $scope.update = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
      };

      $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
      };

      $scope.reset();
    }]);
</script>
```

Comment: Angular dynamically creates properties on the scope, if they weren't explicitly defined

Comment: You don't have to declare the properties in the controller in order to use them inside a view. But when you do declare them in the controller you can set a default value and also you don't have to check things like `if( typeof($scope.myVar) === "undefined" ) {`to see of the user made any changes in the model or kept it untouched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-model="user.gender"` code in the HTML refers to `$scope.user.gender` in the controller.

Because `$scope.user` is defined already, angular automatically sets the `gender` property on that object. The same thing follows with the `user.email` and `user.name` properties.

When you call `ng-click="update(user)"`, `update(user)` is the same as `update($scope.user)`.

[This section of the angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) better explains how the `$scope` variable works and how it is accessed in the template, I would recommend reading through it, but here is a quick exerpt:

> The concept of a scope in Angular is crucial. A scope can be seen as the glue which allows the template, model and controller to work together. Angular uses scopes, along with the information contained in the template, data model, and controller, to keep models and views separate, but in sync. Any changes made to the model are reflected in the view; any changes that occur in the view are reflected in the model.